# batch file to take the latest from tfs, include the excluded files,and publish the ASP.NET project

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I need to create a batch file that will take the latest of my ASP.NET project from TFS, compile and finally publish the project. This has been implemented. Howewer there are few more things that this batch file needs to take care of which one is that if there are any files in the project in excluded mode should be automatically included in the project through the batch file. I have used visual studio msbuild command line tool to accompolish all my requirements. Please let me know if there is some command which i can use to include the excluded files of the project.

THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including currently excluded files in the compile requires changes in the project file.  You would have to scan the folders to work out what files are excluded, then programmatically change the project file to include them in the appropriate project and then trigger the compile.

There's no command to do this and I must admit I'm curious as to why you would want to since a broken build may not be replicable on developers machines if a problem exists in one of the excluded files.